# How to manually make a qq plot of p-value against uniform distribution?

Tags: p-value, qq-plot

We are require to assess the distribution of P-value, so i want to make a qq-plot for P-value against the uniform distribution manually, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: This leaves unclear whether it is the general idea that is eluding you or you want advice on coding in some specific but unstated software. (The latter would strictly be off-topic here.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will assume that by "uniform", you mean uniform(0,1). Plot the theoretical quantiles ([using your favourite rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot#Heuristics)) vs the empirical quantiles (R code):

```
n =100
y = runif(n)

seq(0.05,1,length(y))
plot(1:n/(n+1),sort(y))
```

Alternatively, you can plot a QQ envelope to see how well the uniform distribution reproduces the data (this is just a visual inspection):

```
n =100
y = runif(n)

seq(0.05,1,length(y))
plot(1:n/(n+1),sort(y),col="red")


for(i in 1:1000){
points(sort(runif(length(y))),sort(y),pch=".")
}
points(1:n/(n+1),sort(y),col="red",pch=16)
```

You can test the assumption of uniform distribution using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

```
ks.test(y,"punif",0,1)
```

Comment: It's just a matter of convention, but I'd underline that you can plot observed (empirical) quantiles on the vertical axis too. Similarly, there are many different recipes for plotting positions, e.g. (rank - 0.5) / sample size as well as rank / (sample size + 1).